# Getting the centriod of a circle Turbo C++

Tags: c++

It's me again. Turbo C++ is real ancient. I got a problem in getting my centriod of a circle, I have written a program to show me the co-ordinates of the centroid but the display shows me -NAN, -NAN instead of numbers. Please advice, thnx.

```
unsigned char *p = rgbImage; //rbgImage = new unsigned char [ 160 * 120 * 4 ]
unsigned char *q = image; //image = new unsigned char [ 160 * 120 * 1 ]
int n = 0;
float LaserX = 0, LaserY = 0;
char* LaserMID = new char[255];

for( int j = 0; j < 120; j++ ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 160; i++ ) {
        *q++ = *p++;
        if ( *q >= Thrshld ) {
            LaserX += j;
            LaserY += i;
            n = n + 1;
        }
    }
}
LaserX = LaserX/n;
LaserY = LaserY/n;
sprintf(LaserMID, "%.1f, %.1f", LaserX, LaserY);
ShowCo->Text = LaserMID;
```

Comment: how do you represent that circle ?

Comment: Let me note, that if rgbImage has 4Bytes per pixel you should also increment p by 4 each round or you will go through each color-channel when copying to q which will only copy a fourth of the image. further you should average the rgb channels to obtain a grey value.

Comment: @Pollano, the circle is a dot spotted by my camera.

Comment: @Nobody, wat do u mean by averaging the rgb channel?

Comment: Your grayscale value is the average of the r, g and b value so grey = (r + g + b)/3. There are also special weights look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale to get further information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that `n` is non-zero prior to your division.

Comment: n = n + 1; this will make it non-zero whenever it enters the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the case where no value pointed by q is greater than your threshold : in that case, n stays at 0 and you end up with a division by 0.

Moreover, I don't understand why you use `*q++ = *p++;` It's hard to read (ok, I never know if ++ happens before or after assignement in both sides)

- adding parenthesis might easy readability
- doing it in one big memcpy will be much more time efficient

Concerning the original data, name of the variable and size seems to point that your p pointer should be incremented more than that (like 3 or 4 instead of 1) to always check the same color and not use all colors and cover 1/3 of the picture (assuming memory representation is pixel_0_r,pixel_0_g,pixel_0_b, pixel_1_r, pixel_1_g, pixel_1_b...

Comment: ++ happens after the process, so the next *q or *p will be +1.

U mean i need to put a else?

Comment: if `*q` is never bigger than your threshold, n stays at 0, you need to handle that case later. concerning the `*p++ = *q++;`, it's just not easy to read and not time efficient but it does work